# Signal R $.connection.chatHub is undefined in my javascript file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, signalr-2

'.chatHub' is undefined on page load after I moved all signal r code to a bundle that gets loaded on every page

I've successfully installed singal r and I can send chat messages from one user to another in my Asp.Net MVC site. But the MS documentation shows the implementation for just a single page, now I want to send the message to another user on a different page.

So I moved the javascript hub connect/initialization code into a file named my-chat.js that gets loaded on every page and I placed the signal r js file and the signal r hubs reference in a bundle like this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/my-base").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.min.js",
                  "~/signalr/hubs",
                  "~/Scripts/my-base/my-chat.js"));
```

and in my layout page it loads in the correct order, like this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/my-base")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

but when I load up the main/first page, 'my-chat.js' calls

> scope.initializeHub()

that looks like this and '$.connection.chatHub' chatHub is undefined

```
scope.initializeHub = function () {
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (message) {
            // do stuff
        };
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                chat.server.send(scope.userId, $('#message').val());
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Is this is the correct way to do this and maybe the

> "~/signalr/hubs"

in the bundle isn't where I should be putting it?

I also tried putting

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the head section of my layout page but that didn't work, threw an error saying 'unable to get proerty 'signalR' of undefined' or null reference

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving the signal R files and everything related out of the bundle and put it all below the last '@Scripts.Render()' area in my layout.